# Redirect homepage to homepage with trailing slash wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, trailing-slash

Hello I am trying to have the redirection done from domain.com -> domain.com/

Is there a way to accomplish this in Wordpress. I've been trying with htaccess, but httpstatus.io keeps showing 200, when actually it should show a 301 redirect.
It is perfectly redirecting all other pages for example domain.com/page -> domain.com/page/, but seems impossible to have this done on the homepage.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is very simply way to solve, *Update Permalinks*
You must also update your Permalinks (Settings -> Permalinks) to Custom Structure, and remove the trailing slash there whis is showing in image. It removes the trailing slash on all your posts.
[image]

Comment: your suggested solution does the opposite of what the is asked in the question.